# how to finish two or more activites created by parent activity in android

Tags: java, android

i am creating an app in which Activity A creates Activity B and Activity A goes to Background and activity B in Foreground..

when back is pressed in activity B then Activity A comes to foreground and Activity B to background..
Now Activity A creates Activity C again Activity A in background and Activity C in foreground..
I.e now C is foreground and activity A,B are in Background

when back is pressed in activity C then Activity A comes to foreground and Activity C to background..

I.e now A is foreground and activity C,B are in Background

now if Back is pressed in Activity A den i should finish All activities i.e A,B,C and should close the app...

how to implement this can any one help me out..

Comment: **when back is pressed in activity B then Activity A comes to foreground and Activity B to background** - No, when the `BACK` button is pressed, Activity B will be killed. As is any `Activity` when the `BACK` button is pressed.

Comment: when I call Finish() in activity A than Activity B  coming foreground from background... i wont call Finish in Activity B .....i should finish all activites when Activity A is finishd and should Exit the application.. my application is like Gtalk i.e you have peerlist and i can open how many chat window i need wit online peers when i click back on peerlist then all chat window will close and application closes.

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behavior of Android. You don't have to do anything special for this.

Comment: when I call Finish() in activity A than Activity B  coming foreground from background... i wont call Finish in Activity B .....i should finish all activites when Activity A is finishd and should Exit the application.. my application is like Gtalk i.e you have peerlist and i can open how many chat window i need wit online peers when i click back on peerlist then all chat window will close and application closes.

Comment: Why are you calling `finish` at all? Just let the default back button behavior happen.